# Connection refused - socket

Tags: android, sockets

I'm creating an android app. It requires a TCP socket connection to send data to the another device.

Everything works fine for the first time transfer. However when I connect it the second time, it says connection refused by the host or bind error.

I did all possible things to solve this bind error and connection refused. I shutdown both reading and writing end once the transfer is complete, set socket option to re use address, lingering option.

These things work fine when I exit the application completely and open it again but it does not work when I try to open the connection without exiting.

Kindly, help me figure out whether the problem is something related with sockets or with the application, and any ideas how this could be solved?

Comment: Do you have any code that could help us help you isolate the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that that connection from the server side is also properly closed before connecting it second time

Comment: sorry.. i m not allowed to share the code ... i checked whether all the connections are closed... everything is perfectly closed...

Comment: I guess. you are asking the client to reconnect everytime but the connection already exists.. either close the server and client and restart ( like by sending some text like "end" through the outputstream ... or stop connecting repeatedly.. and from the second time just send the file

Answer (score 0):

Look at the output of netstat -a after you close the socket on the server side and before you retry anything.  If your ipaddress/port pair is still in any state other than, I think TIME_WAIT, you will not be able to reconnect.
The server side (the one that calls `accept`) is most likely the culprit, but I'd check both now that you see something wrong.